# Downloading image/text file using 'iframe'

Tags: extjs, extjs4, download

I am using Extjs - 4.1.0 and I want to prompt download window. I used 'iframe'. The window displays only when the file being posted is zip/mp3 but when the file being posted is text/image file, the window doesn't appear.  Is there some property to be set to enable download window for text/image/different files?

Please find my code below.

```
    var record = item.findParentByType('itemcontextmenu').record;
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url : ORT.Configuration.DOWNLOAD_GRAPHICS_URI+"&graphics="+record.get('id'),
            success: function (response, opt) {

                result = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                try {Ext.destroy(Ext.get('graphicsDownloadIframe'));}catch(e) {}
                Ext.core.DomHelper.append(document.body, {
                    tag: 'iframe',
                    id:'graphicsDownloadIframe',
                    css: 'display:none;visibility:hidden;height:0px;',
                    src: result.fileName,
                    frameBorder: 0,
                    width: 0,
                    height: 0
                });
            }   
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

It's all about the mimetype and what your browser does with it. So I guess your problem will the that. Which likely will cause the browser to handle the received file different.

**Edit**

Following is a helper class that I still use

```
Ext.ux.util.HiddenForm = function(url,fields){
    if (!Ext.isArray(fields))
        return;
    var body = Ext.getBody(),
        frame = body.createChild({
            tag:'iframe',
            cls:'x-hidden',
            id:'hiddenform-iframe',
            name:'iframe'
        }),
        form = body.createChild({
            tag:'form',
            cls:'x-hidden',
            id:'hiddenform-form',
            action: url,
            target:'iframe'
        });

    Ext.each(fields, function(el,i){
        if (!Ext.isArray(el))
            return false;
        form.createChild({
            tag:'input',
            type:'text',
            cls:'x-hidden',
            id: 'hiddenform-' + el[0],
            name: el[0],
            value: el[1]
        });
    });

    form.dom.submit();

    return frame;
}
```

Usage

```
Ext.ux.util.HiddenForm('http://localhost/file/fetch',[['PropName','PropValue'],['Prop2Name','Prop2Value']])
```

The server take these arguments and build up a sort of 'FileStreamResult' which trigger a download on the clientside. If you are using a language like .Net or Java then there are already implementations you can use, if you are using PHP you might find **[this](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2007/08/12/how-to-force-file-download-with-php/)** helpful. Anyway, look at your backend...

Comment: Does it mean I have to do some setting in the browser without changing my code mentioned above?

Comment: @Supereme No, you need to look a the server and what you write in the header there. The mimetyp, filename, and so on are important otherwise the browser will not recognize it as download.

Comment: Currently I am using a static json.. Do I need to set the defaultHeaders in the Ajax.request? But I did using that(trying to set 'Accept-Encoding'). It doesn't seem to work but and not getting overridden. Its default value is: 'gzip, deflate'

Comment: @Supereme I guess you misunderstood me; I didn't talked about the frontend, I talked about your server which streams the file back to the client. It all depends on that response of the server... I will post my version of hidden iframe helper which I use...

Comment: Yes please, it will help me a lot

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20261/discussion-between-supereme-and-sra)